# C++ : a helper to compare variadic unsigned int templates parameters

Tags: c++, c++11, helper, variadic-templates

In a class that mixes CRTP, variadic templates, metaprogrammation and operator overloading, I would like to compare two variadic unsigned int templates parameters in order to do some static assertion. I think that helper structs would be a good way to do this but I don't know exactly how to do it. I think about something of the form :

```
template<unsigned int... TDIM, unsigned int... TDIM0> struct HelperCheckDimensions
{
    static const bool ok = /* SOMETHING */
};
```

where `TDIM` and `TDIM0` are the two parameters I want to compare. It will allow me to type :

```
static_assert(HelperCheckDimensions<TDIM..., TDIM0...>::ok, "ERROR : Dimensions are different !");
```

I want the result to be true only if `sizeof...(TDIM)==sizeof...(TDIM0)` AND `TDIM[0] == TDIM0[0], TDIM[1] == TDIM0[1], ..., TDIM[n] == TDIM0[n]`.

How to do that ?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say a class variadic-template  of this form doesn't make sense:

```
template<unsigned int... TDIM, unsigned int... TDIM0> 
struct HelperCheckDimensions
{
    //..
};
```

It doesn't make sense, because if I write this:

```
HelperCheckDimensions<1,2,3,4,5,6> z;
```

then what `TDIM` and `TDIM0` should be? How the compiler should do partition of the arguments?

Is this correct:

```
TDIM = (1,2)
TDIM0 = (3,4,5,6)
```

Or is this correct:

```
TDIM = (1)
TDIM0 = (2,3,4,5,6)
```

Or this:

```
TDIM = (1,2,3,4)
TDIM0 = (5,6)
```

Hope that helps why it doesn't make sense.

---

From your comment:

> Very good point ! But my question remains open... Maybe something of the form `template<unsigned int... TDIM, typename TFAKE, unsigned int... TDIM0>` would work ? What is the best solution?

Well the template definition of this form is not allowed by the Standard:

```
template<unsigned int... TDIM, typename TFAKE, unsigned int... TDIM0>
```

I don't know the reasons why the Standard doesn't allow it even though it makes sense to me, at least in this case (maybe it adds unworthy complexity to the language). According to the Standard, the *template-parameter-pack* must be the *last* parameter of a template definition.

If you compile the above code in GCC, it gives this error:

> error: parameter pack 'TDIM' must be at the end of the template parameter list

Hope that helps.

Comment: Very good point ! But my question remains open... Maybe something of the form template<unsigned int... TDIM, typename TFAKE, unsigned int... TDIM0> would work ? What is the best solution ?

Comment: I think they did not allow it partly because this may have caused errors that they could not think of back then. A security in a sense, that may be lifted up later if they think there really is no problem. It would not be the first time/

Answer (score 1):

Primary class templates can't have two parameter packs , you need to use some pack wrapper

```
template<unsigned int...T> struct intPack;
template<typename T, typename Y> struct HelperCheckDimensions;

template<unsigned int lhs, unsigned int...T, unsigned int rhs, unsigned int...Y> struct HelperCheckDimensions<intPack<lhs,T...>, intPack<rhs, Y...>>
{
static const bool value = lhs==rhs && HelperCheckDimensions<intPack<T...>, intPack<Y...>>::value;
};
template<unsigned int lhs, unsigned int rhs> struct HelperCheckDimensions<intPack<lhs>, intPack<rhs>>
{
static const bool value = lhs==rhs;
};
```

Test: http://liveworkspace.org/code/200e10548f3fc589f39401ca0b22e7c8

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your primary template looks like this:

```
template <int ...> struct Foo;
```

You can now make a `Foo` comparator:

```
template <typename, typename> struct FooCmp : std::false_type { };

template <int A, int B, int ...As, int ...Bs>
struct FooCmp<Foo<A, As...>, Foo<B, Bs...>>
: std::integral_constant<bool, A == B && FooCmp<Foo<As...>, Foo<Bs...>>::value>
{ };

template <> struct FooCmp<Foo<>, Foo<>> : std::true_type { };
```

Usage:

```
typedef Foo<1, 3, 4> F1;
typedef Foo<9, 5, 1> F2;

template <typename S, typename T>
std::enable_if<FooCmp<S, T>::value> do_magic(S s, T t) { /* ... */ }

do_magic(F1{}, F2{});
```

Comment: Is this allowed : `template <int A, int B, int ...As, int ...Bs>`? GCC says,  *parameter pack  must be at the end of the template parameter list*

Comment: @Nawaz that's valid since packs appears in partial specialization

Comment: @Mr.Anubis: With packs the only sensible thing you can do is unpack and treat them as head plus tail.